# Coredata и MapKit

Tags: objective-c, apple, coredata, карты

Я имею в CoreData атрибуты долготы и широты типа `Double`. Я создаю класс для синглтона

```
.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "AddMan.h"

//OutgoingUser
@interface usersIndex : NSObject

//@property (nonatomic) AddMan* user;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *longtitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;

+ (usersIndex *)sharedManager;
+ (void) del;

@end
```

и в моём .m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "usersIndex.h"

@interface usersIndex ( )
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

@end

@implementation usersIndex

 static usersIndex *sharedMyManager = nil;

+ (usersIndex *)sharedManager {

    static dispatch_once_t once;

    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [usersIndex new];

    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

+ (void) del {

    sharedMyManager.longtitude = NULL;
    sharedMyManager.latitude = NULL;

}
```

Я создаю `ViewController` и подключил MapKit. В моём классе мне нужно показать все маркеры из основных данных. Как я могу осуществить это? У меня есть версия о том, как это можно сделать, но я не совсем понимаю.

```
for (int i = 0; i <_users.count; i ++) {
     _index = i;

     CustomMKPointAnnotation * myAnnot = [[CustomMKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
     NSManagedObject * obj = [_users objectAtIndex: _index];
     theCoordinate.latitude = [[obj valueForKey: @ "lantitude"] doubleValue];
     theCoordinate.longitude = [[obj valueForKey: @ "longitude"] doubleValue];
     myAnnot.coordinate = theCoordinate;
     myAnnot.indexAnnotation = i;
     myAnnot.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "% @", [obj valueForKey: @ "name"]];
     myAnnot.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "% @", [obj valueForKey: @ "lastname"]];

     [Self.totalMapView addAnnotation: myAnnot];
}
```

Как я немного понял, нужно создать отдельный класс с массивом в который и поместить всё. А уже в классе `MapVC` выводить через цикл, который приведён выше.

Есть у кого идеи, как использовать этот код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Во первых - использовать синглтон как сущность - нельзя. Хорошее пособие, как начать работать с core data - [ссылка](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone-core-data-your-first-steps--mobile-752);
2. Во вторых, необходимо заполнить и сохранить эти сущности в core data;
3. В третьих создать свойство, в контроллере, которое будет хранить в себе все точки:
   `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mapPoints;`
4. В четвертых, ознакомится придется с азами работы с map kit - [ссылка](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial). Имея сущности с координатами, их будет очень просто отобразить на карте.

Не имея опыта работы (необходимого теоретического минимума, хотя бы) ни с core data, ни с map kit, к сожалению, просто так сделать то, что вы писали, не получится. Если после прочтения этих двух туториалов, останутся вопросы, обращайтесь сюда, в комменты, к этому ответу, буду рад помочь.